# How do I get the values of my spreadsheet columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, google-sheets

I'm new to apps script and javascript but I managed to get all the defined value numbers or column numbers right except for one that is about 200 columns to the right. But column numbers don't always ad up as it seems like it skips some empty columns sometimes but not others for some reason. Is there a way to number the columns with a script? I found this one which runs successfully but I don't know how to print the result.

```
function getValue() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to print the result to? What do you mean by `Is there a way to number the columns`? Can you share a santised copy of your sheet?

Comment: I'll have to delete all the data in the sheet as it's confidential financial info, is that okay? What I mean though is that I need this number: ``` var regNumberCC = e.values[?]; ```

Comment: All the other values was easier to find because their columns were close to the left. But this one is far to the right and I tried to skip empty columns but to no avail. Not skipping any didn't work either

Comment: Which column do you want to get the values of? Column E? Unfortunately `var regNumberCC = e.values[?];` in't quite enough information on its own. You can take your time and sanitise the sheet of any private information.

Comment: Whey are you mentioning `e.values` in a comment? Will you call this function by on submit form installable trigger? Does the linked form allows empty answers? Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details into the question body.

Answer (score 0):

```
function numberColumns() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getMaxColumns());
  var v=rg.getValues()[0].map(function(e,i){return i+1;});
  sh.insertRowBefore(1);//inserts a row first to hold column numbers
  rg.setValues([v]);
}
```